# Postgresql how to convert string to enum type

Tags: postgresql

After import csv file, we get data in text type. But, my attribute in the new table is an ENUM type. Then, how can I convert this ?

Example :The excel imported table contain's gender with m and f.

My postgresql table have gender too, but the attribute is ENUM type ('m', 'f').

Comment: Generally, the enum type columns take string values only, which match to the respective entries in enum. Are you getting any error because your text entries are already in the same notation?

Comment: Ok, I founnd the solution. I made a mystake before. The way is this : INSERT INTO new_table ( col)
    SELECT  col::gender      
  FROM old_table

Comment: Do post the solution as an answer to the question so that others looking for same question may get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE gender AS ('m', 'f');

INSERT INTO new_table (col)
SELECT col::gender FROM old_table;
```

I don t understand where was my mystake...